# What is the equivalent in swift for a static block in Java

Tags: swift, static, block

How to put a static block in Swift, like here in Java? 
I have tried the `static var block = {}`
but that doesn't work right. It has to called exclusively.

What I want is like in Java, the entire block within the static braces are executed when the class is initialized. Something like that in Swift. I have searched all over the internet and not one soul has an answer! A similar functionality or workaround would also do.

```
public class EnumRingLevel
{
   public static final EnumRingLevel DEFAULT = new EnumRingLevel(
      0, 0, "DEFAULT", 1000, 2000);

   public static final EnumRingLevel SILENT = new EnumRingLevel(
      10, 1, "SILENT", 1001, 2001);

   public static final EnumRingLevel QUIET_BEEP = new EnumRingLevel(
      20, 2, "QUIET_BEEP", 1002, 2002);

   public static final EnumRingLevel NORMAL_BEEP = new EnumRingLevel(
      30, 3, "NORMAL_BEEP",1003, 2003);

   private final int gdbval;
   private final int gindex;

   public final String ginternalname;

   private final int gcaptionId;
   private final int gdisplaycaptionId;

   private static EnumRingLevel[] gRingLevelsSortedOnIndex = null;
   private static String[] gCaptionsSortedOnIndex = null;

   static
   {
      gRingLevelsSortedOnIndex = new EnumRingLevel[6];

      gRingLevelsSortedOnIndex[0] = DEFAULT;
      gRingLevelsSortedOnIndex[1] = SILENT;
      gRingLevelsSortedOnIndex[2] = QUIET_BEEP;
      gRingLevelsSortedOnIndex[3] = NORMAL_BEEP;
      gRingLevelsSortedOnIndex[4] = LOUD_BEEP;
      gRingLevelsSortedOnIndex[5] = CUSTOM;


      gCaptionsSortedOnIndex = new String[6];

      for(int i=0;i<gRingLevelsSortedOnIndex.length;i++)
      {
         gCaptionsSortedOnIndex[i] = gRingLevelsSortedOnIndex[i].getCaption();
      }
   }

   private EnumRingLevel(
      int dbval, int index, String internalname
      , int captionResource, int displaycaptionResource)
   {
      //private constructor

      gdbval = dbval;
      gindex = index;
      ginternalname = internalname;
      gcaptionId = captionResource;
      gdisplaycaptionId = displaycaptionResource;

   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
private static var gRingLevelsSortedOnIndex: [EnumRingLevel] = {
    return [DEFAULT, SILENT, QUIET_BEEP, NORMAL_BEEP, LOUD_BEEP, CUSTOM]
}()
```

Comment: hmm.. i see.. nice